# Center by absolute position work fine in Chrome but not in latest versions of IE and Firefox

Tags: css, cross-browser

I want to center this headline vertically:

```
<div class="headline>
    <div class="field-wrapper">
       <h1>Pressrelease</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

... by using absolute posiitioning like this:

```
.headline {
    position: relative;
}    
.field-wrapper{
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        bottom: 0px;
        margin-top: auto;
        margin-bottom: auto;
    }
```

This works in (latest versions of) Chrome but not in Firefox and IE. What do I need to do to center vertically in all browsers?

Comment: You can use flex :)

Comment: @vAhy_The Flex isn't supported in IE...

Comment: Thanks guys, the second answer in this question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/396145/how-to-vertically-center-a-div-for-all-browsers) did the trick for me. Problem solved.

Comment: You need to add this also .field-wrapper { display:flex;align-items:center; } and also add this .headline{ height : 100%;}

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman for how old ie you develop ??

Comment: @vAhy_The Some banks still use IE 6. Some fintech firms still support IE 7. Hope that helps! 